# software update option not appearing in eclipse using ubuntu

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

I just installed eclipse on ubuntu OS . I was going to install android but before to install ADT plug in, I cound not find Help->Software updates.. Kindly suggest me what I am missing here.

Thanks,

Comment: What version of Eclipse do you use? Did you install it via the Ubuntu Software catalog?

Comment: No I not installed from catalog . Version: 4.2.0
Build id: I20120127-1145

Comment: When I tried to install by "Ubuntu Software center" I had these error messages ::Check your internet connection.Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-6/openjdk-6-jdk_6b23~pre11-0ubuntu1.11.10_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.167 80]                                                                 However my internet connection is working.

Comment: But why 4.2? It is not even released, the update site for it are not active. Try 3.7 if you don't need specifics of 4.2. By the way the menu items are labelled "Check for Updates" and "Install New Software...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have installed an old version of eclipse from the software manager. I think you use Ubuntu 10.04 and there is a 3.5 eclipse version.

You have to update your eclipse. I've found a very good [tutorial](http://flurdy.com/docs/eclipse/install.html) how to do this. Everything works in my case.