# Eclipse "Help->Software Update" option missing

Tags: eclipse

The Software Update option is missing from my help menu in Eclipse, version "Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)." I acknowledge that a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228744/software-update-option-not-appearing-in-eclipse-using-ubuntu) has been posed, but I am running Windows 8. My end goal is to install the FindBugs plugin.

Thanks for your time.

[Screenshot of Help Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xale.png)

Comment: have you tried `install new software`?

Comment: I hadn't, but this worked. I was stuck on what must be out of date instructions from wiki.eclipse.org ("What is the Update Manager") and findbug's Eclipse update site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will better suggest to use latest eclipse release `mars.1` release for latest features of eclipse.

If you don't have choice to move to mars.1 , you follow this steps.

Help --> Install new software.
Press Add.
Give Name `Find bugs`
Give Location `http://findbugs.cs.umd.edu/eclipse`
And then select all features you want and `finish`.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Help > Software Update' menu was removed from Eclipse some time ago.

Use the 'Help > Install New Software' menu to install new software on recent Eclipse releases.